# ...return Math.random() meaning?

Tags: node.js, return, operator-keyword, spread

everyone.

I am confused when I see this code.
What does this code mean? Why spread operator is used before return here?

I tried this code with node, and it says `Unexpected token 'return'`

Fyi, this code snippet is from nodejs document.

```
function generateRandom() {
...return Math.random()
}
```

Appreciate for any explanation.

Comment: At that point, it means nothing, because it's a syntax error. With proper syntax, it refers to either object rest/spread or array (/ iterable) rest/spread.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So nodejs document shows grammatically wrong code snippet??

Comment: What do you mean, "nodejs document"? Are you referring to something in the official documentation or something? That sounds very strange, have a link?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes I do, as I mentioned in the question apparently. https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those dots are not actually part of the code. They are a part of the Node REPL only, an indicator to the user, after they press enter, that the statement you've typed is not complete. As [the link where you found this code says](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl):

> The Node REPL is smart enough to determine that you are not done writing your code yet, and it will go into a multi-line mode for you to type in more code.

That is, if you start typing:

```
function generateRandom() {
```

and then press enter, you'll see the following

```
function generateRandom() {
...
```

with the text cursor at the end of the `...`, indicating that you need to finish the statement before the REPL executes it.

So

```
function generateRandom() {
...return Math.random()
}
```

when you take out the REPL's visual indicator that you're in multi-line mode, is just

```
function generateRandom() {
return Math.random()
}
```

which is syntactically correct.